# Showing that this is a subspace iff a constant is zero

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $b ∈ F$, then
>
> ${[(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) ∈ \mathbb{F^4} : x_3 = 5x_4 + b]}$
>
> is a subspace of $\mathbb{F^4}$ if and only if $b = 0$, as you should verify.

The first  example in my book under subspaces is this. The author wants me to verify this statement, but I dont know why b must be zero for this to hold true. Please help.

---

I think the first  step would be to write it as :

${[(x_1, x_2, 5x_4 + b, x_4) ∈ \mathbb{F^4} : x_3 = 5x_4 + b]}$

Now there are three things to consider:

1) $0 ∈ F$ This is true, because  we can multiply 0 as a scalar so:

$0(x_1, x_2, 5x_4 + b, x_4)=(0,0,0,0)$

**This raised a big question, I can multiply set of vectors by 0, and  satisify the first condition. So why is there such a check even ? I think I'm not allowed to multiply by 0, because otherwise checking if the condition is met is better off assumed for everything. Is this wrong?** If I am wrong, can someone say what is the proper method to checking that $O ∈ F$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The zero vector must be in every subspace.

Comment: Thank you very much , Please read my question. I added content to the bottom as to how I verified that it would contain 0 even if b is not zero.

Comment: @TheArtist, you're overcomplicating it. Look at the conditions for a subspace. Apply them. Done.

Comment: Yes but how I have understood, b does not have to be zero. I don't know how to check if the condition is properly met :/ Coz we can do a scalar multiplication where the scalar is 0 , so if we do that the space contains 0 irrespective of what value b is.

Comment: Oh I got it :D since x4 needs to be zero, when x4 is zero then x3 is 0+b , and this should be equal to zero so b=0. Thank you a lot.